# Error while executing the testNG.xml file

Tags: java, testng

I am getting the error below while executing the Java `testNG.xml` file in Eclipse:

```
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "
http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail 
or not work as expected.
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >` to the top of the file..?

Comment: testNG.xml is is not a java file

Answer (score 3):

i have downgrade my testng-6.14.3 from testng 7.x.x now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Add `<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >` this line in testng.xml file, It will be second one line of testng.xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

Answer (score 2):

I have upgraded my testNG version in POM.xml from 6.14.3 to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Changing version solved this error.

Answer (score 1):

it helped me to replace http protocol to https
so the line is

`<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons for this error.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >  is not present in your testng .xml
```

2. which I faced recently your Java version is not compatible with your testng version.

for #2 better to update testng version

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.properties for for any syntax error and correct it.
Example: any property would have special character( ; or :  etc..) at the end of the line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).